# Manually run GTK event loop

Tags: mono, unity-game-engine, gtk

I am trying to integrate GTK (in a .NET application via the gtk-sharp bindings) into an application that already has a "main loop." Calling `Gtk.Application.Run()` results in the entire thing basically locking up while waiting on the Gtk loop. Furthermore, this app can't really be integrated into GTK in the usual sense (that is, using GTK's idle stuff to pump the app for events).

Is there a way to do the opposite and run the GTK main event loop manually?

Right now I have something like this:

```
def _pump_gtk():
    while true:
        if Gtk.Application.EventsPending():
            Gtk.Application.RunIteration()
        yield
```

(the yield is because _pump_gtk is running as a coroutine in the main application)

However, this seems to have problems because Gtk doesn't think there is a main loop running? I get a lot of `Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_main_quit: assertion main_loops != NULL' failed` errors.

Is there a way to run the GTK main loop manually?

Comment: Are you trying to break out of your pseudo gtkmainloop via `Gtk.MainLoop.quit()` or similar?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. It's precisely `while ( gtk_main_events_pending() ) gtk_main_iteration();`. I currently do this in a couple of (low-coverage) places with great success (but it makes me feel guilty that I should probably be using signals instead). Without specifying the precise context in which you are attempting to manually run the main loop, we cannot possibly speculate as to why you get any error from doing so.